# Are Custom Class DataBinding Possible in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

in WPF, I was successfully able to bind a custom class into a ListView.

I am trying to achieve the same thing for WinForm.

I have a DataGridView dvg1;

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Automobile A = new Automobile();
        A.Manufactor = "Mazda";
        A.HorsePower = "148 HP";
        A.CarName = "3";

        dvg1.DataSource = A;

        dvg1.DataBindings.Add("Text", A, "Manufactor");
        dvg1.DataBindings.Add("Text", A, "HorsePower");
        dvg1.DataBindings.Add("Text", A, "CarName");
    }
}

public class Automobile
{
    public string Manufactor { get; set; }
    public string HorsePower { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
}
```

I am not too sure what to do here. I want to populate dvg1 with items from Automobile. I want items on dvg1 item value to change when an item is updated.

For example, if A.CarName changes from "3", to "Speed", I want that to be reflected on dvg1.

Am I looking at the right approach? or is this only on WPF?

Comment: `I am trying to achieve the same thing for WinForm` - expecting to get WPF features from winforms is like expecting my grandma to drive a Ferrari at 350 mph while headbanging to Slipknot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Bind a `List(Of Automobile)` to the DGV. It will automatically assign columns for each property.

```
List<Automobile> myAutos = New List<Automobile>;
//add automobiles then bind
dgv.DataSource = myAutos;
```

Comment: Yes, I will. I am just having trouble with something currently. For some reason, When I add more than 1 new Automobile();, all of them becomes null except the last one

Comment: Automobile A = new Automobile();
            A.Manufactor = "Mazda";
            A.HorsePower = "148 HP";
            A.CarName = "3";


            Automobile A1 = new Automobile();
            A.Manufactor = "Nissan";
            A.HorsePower = "126 HP";
            A.CarName = "Sentra";


            Automobile A2 = new Automobile();
            A.Manufactor = "Honda";
            A.HorsePower = "112 HP";
            A.CarName = "Civic";


            AutoList.Add(A);
            AutoList.Add(A1);
            AutoList.Add(A2);

Comment: Look at your variables you are assigning all the values to `A`.

Comment: oops Lol. today's not my day obviously.